# vite error when importing surrealdb.wasm into tauri project

Tags: javascript, vite, tauri, surrealdb

I have problems on running surrealdb.wasm on a tauri project. I have installed the library, but when i try to do `import { Surreal } from 'surrealdb.wasm';`, vite gives me compiling error in development:

```
Error: Build failed with 6 errors:
node_modules/surrealdb.wasm/dist/full/index.js:8:13: ERROR: Top-level await is not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2020", "firefox78", "safari14" + 2 overrides)
... and more alike errors ...
```

I have tried to set `build.target` and `esbuild.target` to `esnext`, but it does not seem to change anything. I have also tried to add the [top-level-await](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-top-level-await) plugin which changes all `await` 's to `.then()`, but this makes the compiler unable to find the library, for some reason:

```
Error: Not found: /node_modules/.vite/deps/index_bg.wasmat resolve (C:/my/directory/project_name/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:480:13)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot remember where i found the answer, but it works to add `surrealdb.wasm` to `optimizeDeps.exclude`:

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [ sveltekit() ],
    optimizeDeps: {
        exclude: ['surrealdb.wasm'],
    }
});
```